# Column Name Conflict on Laravel 4 Fluent Query Builder

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have a query like this:

```
$users = DB::table('users')->join('user_roles','users.role_id','=','user_roles.id')->get();
```

and a table that has a column `id` (users.id) and another table that has columns `id` and `user_id` (user_roles.id & user_roles.user_id),

but the problem is.. what is being returned on `$user->id` is the `user_roles.id` instead of the `users.id` column.. how do i fix this so that what i get is not the role id but the user id instead..

thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Found it!

using `->select('users.*', 'user_roles.role_name')` i was able to remove `user_roles.id` from the returned values and thus eliminating the conflict.

Here is the final query:

```
$users = DB::table('users')->join('user_roles','users.role_id','=','user_roles.id')->select('users.*', 'user_roles.role_name')->get();
```

Comment: an alternative although poor solution is `->select('*', 'users.id')`

Answer (score 6):

The better way to do this is using 'as':

```
$users = DB::table('users')->join('user_roles','users.role_id','=','user_roles.id')->get(array('users.*', '**user_roles.id as user_roles_id**', 'user_roles.*'));
```